# Closing connections with github GraphQL API

Tags: http, github, graphql

When establishing connection with database it is good to close the db connection normally. Does the same apply for HTTP connections? I tried to send request to Github GraphQL API to get repositories and pull requests of each repository. I send requests separately by establishing end points.

So is it good to close the connection? If so, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Clean up some grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we dont close http connections, since it expires after certain period of time.